# Module with ContentProvider

Tags: android, module, android-contentprovider

I'm ussing [this](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray) library, the problem starts with:

> Tray is based on a ContentProvider. A ContentProvider needs a unique
>   **authority**. When you use the same authority for multiple apps you will
>   be unable to install the app due to a authority conflict with the
>   error message:
>
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]

because i didn't read this before, i used this library to fix problems with multi thread SharedPreference, this project had to become in a module to use in multiple projects.

At the moment of installing every App with this Module, throws the **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]** exception.

Because **authority** is already used in the first installed app.

---

### The questions are:

- How can i skip installation of Module that is already installed? (Installing the rest of the app, so error will disapear)
- else, How can i structure the projects? to be able to install multiple apps built with the Module that have the ContentProvider Library.

---

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed

For those that need something similar these are the steps to follow:

**Step 1.** I configured Tray Library in a **Main Project** "required for the rest of apps" 
(the app that hosts database preferences)

**Step 2.** I extracted from repository the required classes to connect with the Tray ContentProvider, which are:

> - AbstractTrayPreference.java
> - ContentProviderStorage.java
> - ItemNotFoundException.java
> - Migration.java
> - OnTrayPreferenceChangeListener.java
> - PreferenceAccessor.java
> - Preferences.java
> - PreferenceStorage.java
> - SqliteHelper.java
> - TrayContract.java
> - TrayDBHelper.java
> - TrayException.java
> - TrayItem.java
> - TrayPreferences.java
> - TrayProviderHelper.java
> - TrayRuntimeException.java
> - TrayStorage.java
> - TrayUri.java
> - WrongTypeException.java

in a new package for the common Module.

**Step 3.** I hardcoded authority name via constant variable:

This must match with **Main Project** configuration:

```
// bild.gradle of Main Project
resValue "string", "tray__authority", "<your.app.package>.tray"


// TrayContract.java of Module
@NonNull
private static String getAuthority(@NonNull final Context context) {
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(sTestAuthority) ?
            AppConstant.TRAY_AUTHORITY: // <-- this one = <your.app.package>.tray
            sTestAuthority;
}
```

**Finally** I can use the class normally:

```
// etc
import <your.app.package>.tray.TrayPreferences;
// etc
public class AppPreferencesManager extends TrayPreferences {
// etc
}
```

it worked :)