# Can an instant app use an internally accessible content provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-instant-apps

The [Instant Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/prepare.html#additional-reqs) says that the following features are unsupported for instant apps:

- Externally accessible content providers
- Access to content providers from other applications

I am currently refactoring an Android app so that it supports instant apps. This app uses a content provider for storing data and is not externally accessible.

I wanna know if it is possible to use a content provider within an instant app which is only accessible inside that specific app. Currently it does instantiate the content provider but the content resolver returns null when trying to retrieve the provider. It does work with the installable app.

Comment: Maybe some info in this question provides some insights https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510925/module-with-contentprovider

Comment: "This app uses a content provider for storing data" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare It implements the AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter, CursorAdapter and CursorLoader classes as stated in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html).

Comment: A `ContentProvider` is used to publish data to other apps. You do not need to use it internally.

Comment: Regardless of wether ContentProvider should be used, the question still remains... Is it possible? If the existing app is already using it, it can be Troublesome to refactor

Comment: @CommonsWare some apps use internal contentproviders for cursoradapters - it was a common way of doing things a few years ago

Comment: How are you registering the content provider / are there different namespaces between the content provider and the instant app module?

Comment: You can use the ContentProvider, but the SyncAdapter with its associated account will break at runtime since it's not accessible within an instant app.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer I figured that out as I have the ContentProvider working but the instant app crashes on the ContentResolver.requestSync method. The problem with my ContentProvider was a string resource in the AndroidManifest which did not get replaced somehow. Is there any way to work with the SyncAdapter or what is an alternative?

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787